# How to sort smaller values between two columns in R?

Tags: r, sorting

I have a dataframe called test. I want to sort the dataframe and move the smaller values in the left column (`sstart`) and keep the bigger values on the right column (`send`). I can do this by using if else condition and creating two new columns with sorted values. How can we do this more efficiently in R?

```
test<- structure(list(sstart = c(425L, 387L, 436L, 219L, 
232L), send = c(125L, 487L, 136L, 3191L, 132L
)), .Names = c("sstart", "send"), row.names = c(4L, 14L, 17L, 
23L, 27L), class = "data.frame")
```

Result I want:

```
sstart send
125  425 
387  487
136  436 
219  3191
132  232
```

Comment: You can use `pmax` and `pmin`, but it is impossible to swap two values without temporarily storing at least one value.  I can understand that you do not want to  add new (temp) columns, but would it be OK for a solution to use temp vectors outside of the `data.frame`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pmax` and `pmin`, but it is impossible to swap two values without temporarily storing at least one value:

```
# temp vectors of the columns to "swap" the values as required
low  <- pmin(test$sstart, test$send)
high <- pmax(test$sstart, test$send)

# exchange the columns
test$sstart <- low
test$send   <- high

# result
test

#   sstart send
# 4     125  425
# 14    387  487
# 17    136  436
# 23    219 3191
# 27    132  232
```

**Warning:** If `NA`s occur in your data you may loose information since. You could set `NA`s to a decent default value as work-around:

E. g. if you add another row containing an `NA` value

```
test[6,]$sstart <- NA
test[6,]$send <- 100
```

you will get two `NA`s instead of one + the 2nd value:

```
   sstart send
4     125  425
14    387  487
17    136  436
23    219 3191
27    132  232
NA     NA   NA
```

Answer (score 3):

REVISED

Sorry, upon re-reading your question, I see I misunderstood you: You just want to sort within each row the first two columns. That's not what my original code (preserved below) does. What you want is this:

```
data.frame(t(apply(test[,1:2],1,sort))) %>% 
  rename(sstart=X1, send=X2) %>% dplyr::bind_cols(test[,-1:-2])
```

I use apply rowwise (that's the "1" there) on the first two columns of test, with the function applied being sort. This gives us a sideways matrix, so I `t`ranspose it and turn it into a data.frame, and then bind it back to the rest of the original `test`. Result:

```
  sstart send
1    125  425
2    387  487
3    136  436
4    219 3191
5    132  232
```

Sorry about the mix-up.

WRONG CODE:

```
matrix(sort(unlist(test)),ncol=2) %>% data.frame() %>% dplyr::rename(sstart=X1,send=X2)
```

Unlisting test turns it into a vector, which we sort and place into a matrix with two columns. Matrix defaults to filling by column, so the smaller ones will go into the first column and the larger ones into the second. We move this matrix into a data.frame and rename the columns sstart and send. Voila.

```
  sstart send
1    125  387
2    132  425
3    136  436
4    219  487
5    232 3191
```

If there are other columns in test that need to be preserved:

```
matrix(sort(unlist(test[,1:2])),ncol=2) %>% data.frame() %>% 
  dplyr::rename(sstart=X1,send=X2) %>% 
  dplyr::bind_cols(test[,-1:-2])
```

Comment: Looks to me like you just have to limit the `test[,c("sstart","send")]` in the input if there are more columns.

Comment: What @EvanFriedland said.

Comment: Just realized my answer didn't actually give you the result you wanted. Added the correct answer at the top. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this way:

```
split(test,row(test)) %>%
  purrr::map_dfr(~{
    sort(.x) %>% 
    setNames(c("sstart","send"))
  })
```